# Qt and Visual Studio. Tray icon disappearance

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, qt5

I use Qt in Visual Studio and I needed to set a tray icon in the application.
I use the next code:

```
QSystemTrayIcon trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
QIcon trayImage(":/Res/myIcon.ico");
trayIcon->setIcon(trayImage);
trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);
trayIcon->show();
```

My qrc file:

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Res/myIcon.ico</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

And it worked. But when I moved my application to another computer it failed with the error "This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin 'windows'.". I solved it by creating the directory "platforms" in the directory with execution files and putting qwindows.dll in it. But after that the icon disappeared. I see only blank square in the tray. I can use tray icon actions but my image doesn't display.

Thanks for any idea why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read [description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html#details) of [`QIcon`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qicon.html) class, where you can find link to supported formats [`QImageReader::supportedImageFormats()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimagereader.html#supportedImageFormats) and there is no `.ico` format.

I'm not sure, but probably it can be source of your problem. Try to change icon format to another one.

Answer (score 3):

When deploying Qt application to other machines, you'll also need to deploy plugins for the needed image formats. In your case you must create the `imageformats` directory and copy the `qico.dll` plugin (which can be found in the Qt SDK directory).

Nonetheless, I recommend using the PNG format for your tray icon in view of its better portability.

Answer (score 0):

you should use one of the supported format of Image in qt. for example if you use .png format, it will shows.